# having trouble getting for loop to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, coinbase-api

currently using python3

I'm trying to creating a function to pull the prices of cryptocurrencies and have them sent to my phone. I successfully got everything downloaded and working for bitcoin, but the other currencies in my dictionary aren't pulling correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
client = Client(api_key = 'insert coinbase api key', api_secret='insert coinbase api secret', api_version = '2017-12-13')   


def buyPrice():
    priceDict ={ 'BTC-USD': '', 'ETH-USD': '', 'LTC-USD': ''}
    for key in priceDict:
        if priceDict[key] == '':
            current_price = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair =priceDict[key])
            priceDict[key] = current_price['amount']
        else:
            continue
    return priceDict
buyPrice()
```

ex output:

```
{'BTC-USD': '18897.59', 'ETH-USD': '18897.59', 'LTC-USD': '18897.59'}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `if` statement? All the values in the dictionary are initially empty,

Comment: Shouldn't the argument to `client.get_buy_price()` be `key`, not `priceDict[key]`?

Comment: I think the conditional is unnecessary.

Comment: In your line `current_price = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair =priceDict[key])`, you are trying to send to the function that will get your price the **value**, instead of the **key**. You should also do `for key, value in priceDict.items():`, so you can use `value` instead of `priceDict[key]`.

Answer (score 1):

From what you provided, I believe you should do

`client.get_buy_price(currency_pair = key)`

instead of

`client.get_buy_price(currency_pair = priceDict[key])`

As you are giving the parameter `currency_pair` the value of the key, instead of its name.

---

As also stated in my comment, you should do as following to iterate through both your keys and values (this is the corrected version).

```
def buyPrice():
    priceDict ={ 'BTC-USD': '', 'ETH-USD': '', 'LTC-USD': ''}
    for key, value in priceDict.items():
        if value == '':
            current_price = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair = key)
            value = current_price['amount']
        else:
            continue
    return priceDict
```

Answer (score -3):

This should be your iteration method
`for key in priceDict.keys():`

I also advise you use a `if priceDict.get(key)` as it will not only it's faster but it sometimes prevents `KeyError` exceptions

Comment: This should be a comment, it gives a coding tip. And it also doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: Using `for key in priceDict.keys()` rather than just `for key in priceDict` harms readability and forces you to write more obscure code (like `.get()`).

Comment: I agree . my point wasn't really about the loop but about the `map[key]` vs `map.get(key)` and this one has much better performances .otherwise I would have written an iteritems by reflex since the time in my job tuple size in map.items() lead to OOMs and if i am certain to handle each rows then I go with the iterator